# Python send a message over a TCP RS232/Ethernet (port 5000) connection

Tags: python, serial-port

I want to send a message using python to a RS232/Ethernet connection in order to setup a [Philips monitor](https://www.keren.nl/dynamic/media/1/documents/Drivers/The%20SICP%20Commands%20Document%20V2_05%20released.pdf).
I was using `Javascipt` and `HTML` to setup the connection but `javascript socket` wasn't reading the `ACK` sent back from the monitor, so I turned into using python to do it.

I have tried the following:

```
    TCP_IP = '192.168.0.1'
    TCP_PORT = 5000
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    MESSAGE = "090000AC0D090100A0"#set the input as HDMI
    byt=MESSAGE.encode()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.send(byt)
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

this will cause the app to freeze and no response is registered.

Is there a certain way I should be addressing the connection?

Comment: If it's blocking on the *recv* then it's simply because whatever's servicing port 5000 at 192.168.0.1 isn't planning on sending any kind of response. Maybe because it didn't understand what you transmitted. Or maybe it just accepts what you send without any kind of acknowledgement

Comment: You need to send **bytes**, and not some kind of string. I.o.w. it uses binary protocol. Isn’t that obvious?